# How to implement ForeignKey Attribute to Interface

Tags: entity-framework-4, attributes

ForeignKeyAttribute is not workin on Interface?

```
public class Client: CompanyForeignKeyMapper
{
     public int Client;
}

public class CompanyForeignKeyMapper
{
     [ForeignKeyAttribute("Company")]
     int ClientId;
}
```

this code works fine. but when i change the class CompanyForeignKeyMapper to an Interface

```
public interface ICompanyForeignKeyMapper


public class Client: ICompanyForeingKeyMapper --> changed to interface
```

the attribute doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the Client class as in your second example, it no longer inherits from the CompanyForeignKeyMapper class, so it will have no ClientId field. If you want it to inherit from CompanyForeignKeyMapper and for it to implement the ICompanyForeingKeyMapper interface, declare it like this:

```
public class Client: CompanyForeignKeyMapper, ICompanyForeingKeyMapper
```

Alternatively, you can define ClientId as a field for the interface, in which case Client class must implement it and can add its own ForeignKeyAttribute to it:

```
public interface ICompanyForeignKeyMapper
{
    int ClientId;
}


public class Client: ICompanyForeignKeyMapper
{
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("Company")]
    int ClientId;
}
```

Comment: I intended to convert the class CompanyForeignKeyMapper to Interface so basically i copied the functionality from the Class to the ICompanyForeignKeyMapper bacause the purpose is to just implement the functionality not to inherit. The second answer is not applicaple for me because the Client Class is actually autogenerated so i want the [ForeignKeyAttribute] to transfer it to the interface and split the Client to Partial Classes, but still thank you for the input ;)